# How do I use a list of objects to set values using a defined start location in a JTable?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list of objects which I would like to place in a JTable. The map below has an index as the key and an array as the value. The first element of the integer array is the row number and the second is the column number:

```
    mStartLocationMap = new HashMap<Integer, int[]>(); // private static
    mStartLocationMap.put(1,new int[]{0,0});
    mStartLocationMap.put(2,new int[]{1,0});
    mStartLocationMap.put(3,new int[]{0,1});
    mStartLocationMap.put(4,new int[]{1,1});
```

Depending on which index I get, I retrieve the appropriate start location. The table is 16 rows X 24 columns. However, the logic is such that whatever the start location is, the arraylist of objects I have, each object has to be placed in every other cell until I reach the end of the columns. Then, the rows are also incremented every other row as well. Here is what the end product is supposed to look like (this was done when the case is 96 elements in my list with the code posted below:

[image: Expected Result]

Here is my code:

```
    // rowStart and colStart can be 0 or 1
    int counter = 0;
    for(int row=rowStart; row<rowCount ;row=row+2)    // rowcount =16
    {
        for(int col=colStart; col<colCount; col=col+2) // colcount=24
        {
            // myObjs is an ArrayList that contains 96 or less elements. This line throws the exception
            MyObject temp = myObjs.get(counter); 

            myTable.setValueAt(temp,row,col);
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

I know this way will not work but I'm not sure how else fill the table in this pattern without throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I know which line is throwing the error, but I can't figure out another way to achieve what I want - which is to set all the objects from the list into the table no matter what size the list is.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: what's the type of myObjs? If it's array list then how many elements does myObjs holds?

Comment: It's a custom object. myObjs however is an ArrayList.

Comment: forgot to include `counter++` - see update.

Comment: How many elements are in the list?

Comment: It can be any number of elements <= 96, but no more.

Comment: Well, your loop increments the counter about 8 * 12 times, which is exactly 96. If you say that you don't have 96 elements, then of course you'll go out of bounds. So can you please edit your question and expand: How do you want the elements to be displayed exactly, assuming you have 18 or 60 elements, not exactly 96. Why you are skipping every second row. It may help us find better logic for you.

Comment: Makes sense- will update soon.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - Question is updated. I agree another approach in logic may be the answer. Been trying for the past few hours to think of something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want there to be if you have less than 96 is something like:

```
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│*│ │*│ │*│ │*│ │
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤
│*│ │*│ │ │ │ │ │
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
```

In that case, you loop on your **list** and adjust your current row and column rather than the other way around:

```java
    int row = rowStart;
    int col = colStart;
    for( MyObject temp : myObjs ) {
        myTable.setValueAt(temp,row,col);
        col+=2;
        if ( col >= colCount ) {
            col = colStart;
            row+=2;
        }
    }
```

Basically, you start at your `rowStart` and `colStart`. For each value in the list, you add it to the table, and then calculate the next position. First, you move to the next column. If you see that you have exceeded the number of columns, then you need to go to the next row. You adjust the column to your first column again, and update your row.

You don't need to check the limit of the row because you are not supposed to have more elements in your list than you have in your table.

Comment: Yeah, this definitely makes more sense. I've updated my code and it works perfectly. I guess I was too caught up in worrying about the placement. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's crazy is that I started out doing what you did, but then immediately dismissed it without experimenting further and then proceeded to do something opposite :/...lesson learned!

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting exception at this line:

```
MyObject temp = myObjs.get(counter);
```

As your array list would be empty and you are trying to access 0th element.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I know which line throws the error - after trying for a while, I don't know how to achieve what I want.